# Can't get the correct results algolia

Tags: laravel, algolia, laravel-scout

I can't get scout working properly with algolia.

I added the client relationship to the searchable array:

```
public function toSearchableArray()
   {
      $this->client;

      $array = $this->toArray();

       $array = $this->transform($array);

       return $array;
   }
```

And want to search for these attributes:

```
'searchableAttributes' => ['title', 'description', 'client.naam', 'client.email'],
```

when i do:

```
Project::search($keyword)->where('user_id', $request->user_id)->where('finished', true)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
```

i don't get any result. Everything is imported en synced correctly al well.

But the records are uploaded to algolia en indexed correctly and when i search in the algolia dashboard i get the correct results. Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You’ve said your `searchableAttributes` are `['title', 'description', 'client.naam', 'client.email']`

Then you’ve said you’re trying to search using `'user_id'` and `'finished'`.

If that’s correct, then you need to add `user_id` and `finished` to your `searchableAttributes` so that they are searchable.

Comment: I believe that OP is trying to filter the search results? So, adding those attributes just to `attributesForFaceting` as `filterOnly(user_id)` and `filterOnly(finished)` should be enough?